# Load dynamic fields in Microsoft flow custom connector

Tags: power-automate

I'm creating a custom connector in Microsoft flow, it has an action so when there is a new record created in CRM i want to push it to my application using flow.

In my application i have different modules, there is a dropdown to select module in flow, on selection of module I want populate the input fields.i want to know if there is a way to achieve this. I see some existing flow connectors has this feature but i couldn't find the useful resource to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can achieve this.
If the list is static you can use the `enum` attribute and

if your list is dynamic you can use the `x-ms-dynamic-values` property to populate your input fields of any attribute.

Static dropdown example :

```
        "action": {
          "type": "string",
          "description": "",
          "title": "Action",
          "enum": [
            "Car",
            "Bike"
          ]
        }
```

Dynamic dropdown example :

```
{
name: "listID-dynamic",
type: "string",
in: "path",
description: "Select List you want outputs from",
required: true,
x-ms-summary: "Select List",
x-ms-dynamic-values: {
   operationId: "GetLists",
   value-path: "id",
   value-title: "name"
   }
}
```

Complete example can be viewed here :
https://procsi.blob.core.windows.net/docs/sampleDynamicSwagger.json

Here is the detailed documentation for the same : 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/custom-connectors/openapi-extensions#x-ms-dynamic-values